# Pointing PHPWord at an image on localhost with a port number fails

Tags: php, phpword

I am working on a Word exporter for a PHP application using the PHPWord library. When I run the following:

`$section->addImage('http://localhost:8080/path/to/my/file.jpeg',$settings);`

I get an exception saying `invalid image`. But when I point the same function at the same file on a remote server (without a port number), the exception goes away, and I get the image successfully added to my document.

**Is this a known behavior? If so, is there a fix for it?** I have verified that the local image shows up when I access it directly in a browser.